# generate NxN matrix with only 0 and 1

Tags: matrix

What I am trying to do here,is to **generate a full list of matrices with NxN filled with only 1 and 0 using Java**.

I know this should be a large number of matrices in this list when n getting bigger.

The only way I could think of is to build a for loop inside a for loop inside a for loop...and so on.

I don't need this function works on large number of n, 6 is enough. It's huge in my method which needs 36 loops to achieve my goal.

Anybody could come up with a clever solution for my problem?

ps.A recursive function might help but I can't figure out it.

Comment: n "nodes"?? do you mean it's nxn?

Comment: recursion: set the next element to 0, recurse. after that set that same element to 1, recurse. and handle the base case. that's it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yeah,sorry for the typo :)

Comment: you will have 2^(n^2) matrices. with n=6, that's 68.719.476.736

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Could you help me in more details with your recursion?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have encounter this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
    private int[][] matrix; 
    public void CreateMatrix(int n)
    {
        this.matrix = new int[n][n](); //initialize a NxN 2D array
        createMatrixRow(0); //start filling from row 0
    }

    //start filling your matrix row by row
    public void createMatrixRow(int rowNumber)
    {
       if(rowNumber==n) //break the recursion when matrix is full
           return;
       for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
       {
          //assign values in the matrix based on row & column numbers
          matrix[rowNumber][i] = generateValue(rowNumber, i);
       }

       createMatrixRow(rowNumber++); //recurse until your matrix is full
    }


    //Rules for generating values to be included here. I have written sample to generate identity matrix for identity matrix
    public int generateValue(int rowNumber, int columnNumber)
    {
       if(rowNumber == columnNumber)
          return 1;
       else 
          return 0
    }
```